# How to measure fps (elapsed time) with tkinter python.after?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame-rate

I have a function that loops and I want to measure how long it takes to go through one revolution including the time I've added with tkinter.  I added these lines to the bottom of my looping function.

I would expect to see the amount of time change based on the `.after` value but regardless of whether I set it to 25 or 5025, I get the same basic results.  I also experimented with putting the `time2=` statement at the very beginning of the loop and then also swapping the print and `time2=` statements positions.

I get slightly different results with different positions but none of them seem to show the added time of the `.after` value although I can clearly see (based on what the rest of the code does) that the time is being added.

So, I obviously have a "measurement" problem.  Is there a critical piece of knowledge that I'm failing to grasp?

```
print time.clock() - time2[0]     
time2[0] = time.clock()    
root.after(5025, myloop)
```

Comment: you measure time before `after` is executed and before `myloop` is executed so you have to get wrong result. Better show minimal working example because this code is not enough to answer.

Comment: BTW with `5025` you should get about `1000/5025` FPS (about 0.199 FPS) but you have to add time used by command in `myloop` - ie. `1000/(5025+time_in_myloop)` FPS

Comment: time.clock() is deprecated in Python 3.3 - you should use process_time()
However, if you're trying to capture an event driven elapsed time, you may want a delta time.time() instead, as time.clock() and process_time() measure CPU time required to perform the python line

Comment: @furas  My function just contains some stuff that takes time. My thinking is that by setting time2 to the current time at the end of the loop (after the print command) I will see the full duration of the loop by the time the print command comes around again.  Why is this not so?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment above, you can achieve an elapsed time functionality like so:

```
import time

def get_elapsed_time()
    startTime = time.time()
    my_loop()
    endTime = time.time()

    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
    print elapsedTime
```

time.time() represents the passage of time since the Linux *epoch*, which is 1/1/1970 - read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Therefore, the above function will set `startTime` to the "Linux Universal Time", loop through your `my_loop()` function, at the end of which it will set `endTime` to the "Linux Universal Time".  The difference between `endTime` and `startTime` will represent the passage of time between when your get_elapsed_time() function was called and when it ended, which will have been micro-seconds after your `my_loop()` function ends.  Effectively, this will print the amount of time your `my_loop()` function was running.

Comment: this is assuming that my_loop() is the function you are referring to that takes time

Comment: So you suggest using a separate function to do the measuring?  I may give that a try although the function I'm trying to measure needs to loop and I would like to keep a running tally of how long each loop through takes in order to evaluate what elements are adding the most time. It would be difficult to measure various things one loop at a time.  But I'm really curious about why the approach I took did not work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In my code worked this:

```
start = time.time()
app.update() # update the app
fps = 0
original_time = time.time() - start
test = original_time
while test < 1:
    fps += 1
    test += original_time
    if original_time == 0: # if error
        break
if fps != 1:
    print("Fps:", fps) # print fps
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).